# Resource Filtering with Maven Site Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I'm using the [maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) to create and deploy a site of documentation and resources. There are some javascript files that I would like to filter based on what profile is being used. Problem is, I can't figure out how to get the filtering to work. Has anyone come across this?

I'm using Maven 3 and my resources are all in `/src/site/resources` which automagically get copied to `/target/site` by the site plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to filter site resources? I am curious.

Comment: `var SomeService = function() { var baseUrl = '${someServiceBaseUrl}'; ...`

Comment: there is no direct support. BUT the site plugin supports general filtering. This should work out of the box if you have a properties section in your pom (this works for use, I use that). Maybe delcared fiters work too. Just try.

Comment: properties in the pom file doesn't works for me. What do you mean @Michael-O for filters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to name the files you would like to filter as: [filename.vm](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html) which identifies them as velocity macro files which will be filtered automatically.